# how to write state change function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets say the temperature is constant for a 20 minutes, at the 21st minute, it changes.The state change is determined by a programmable state change function.
how can i write function to make get difference of state change.

```
      if(data.id == "Temperature_1")
        {

            this.allInOne_Responses[2] = response;
            if(this.Temperature_1 > this.prevTemp)
            {
                egress = true
                this.prevTemp = this.Temperature_1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [RxJS](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6we3JpI3UAhXJMo8KHX01Bw0QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FReactive-Extensions%2FRxJS&usg=AFQjCNHrMHDtQDbLhov4sutULxApsgoF-g&sig2=QSnyeWz36iWDhgwNW7b6Rg)

these type of variables change requires a observable to be attached to the variable and they note down if any change happens in the values.

you can write down your own observable code too.If you want reference to that let me know in the comments.But i would refer you to use RxJS
syntax be like this

> let  temperature : BehaviorSubject`<any>` = new BehaviorSubject(0);`

and you subscibe to these values and perform accordingly to the changes.

```
this.temperature.subscribe((temperature)=>{
//perform your opertaion here
 })=
```

Comment: is there any possibility to write in typescript only?

Comment: this is typescript only. let me know some more about your functions and i can help you with typescript

Comment: prevtemp = 0
current temp is coming from some source
how do i check temp ,if temp is increased from constant to some change
(Lets say the temperatue is constant for a 20 minutes, at the 21st minute, it changes.)
do i need to write foreach or how it can be?